# How to get my login and register functions to work correctly

Tags: php

I have started the coding so then when a customer is registering a product on the first page (customer_login.php) they type in their email. When they press the login button, it takes them to the product_register.php page where it will display their full name. Then there is a drop down that will allow them to choose the product they are registering. Once completed and they hit the register product button, it is to show on the same page "Product (name of the product chosen) has been registered successfully. I have shown the coding for all the pages below and I am just solely using PHP. It is suppose to work where when the button is pressed, it goes to the index.php and gets the name of the action and then produces what is required.

customer_login.php

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
<main>

    <h2>Customer Login</h2>
    <p>You must login before you can register a product.</p>
    
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Email:
        <input type="text" action="login_customer" class="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Login"></p>

    </form>

</main>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

product_register.php

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
<main>

    <h2>Register Product</h2>
    <?php if (isset($message)) : ?>
        <p><?php echo $first_name;?> </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($customers as $customer) : ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="aligned" name="get_customer">
            <label>Customer:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="name"
                value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['first_name', 'last_name']); ?>"><br>
            <label>Product:</label>
            <select name="get_customer">
                <option value="Draft Manager 1.0">Draft Manager 1.0</option>
                <option value="Draft Manager 2.0">Draft Manager 2.0</option>
                <option value="League Scheduler 1.0">League Scheduler 1.0</option>
                <option value="League Scheduler Deluxe 1.0">League Scheduler Deluxe 1.0</option>
                <option value="Team Manager Version 1.0">Team Manager Version 1.0</option>
                <option value="Tournament Master Version 1.0">Tournament Master Version 1.0</option>
                <option value="Tournament Master Version 2.0">Tournament Master Version 2.0</option>
            </select><br><br>
        
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" action="register_product" value="Add Product" /><br>
            </form>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
        
    <?php endif; ?>
</main>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/customer_db.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');
require('../model/registration_db.php');
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action === NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
        $action = 'get_customer';
    }
}

//instantiate variable(s)
$email = '';

if ($action == 'login_customer') {
    
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');

    if ($email != false) {
        login_customer($email);
    }

    $customers = get_customers();

    include('product_register.php');

} else if ($action == 'get_customer') {
    $get_customer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'get_customer');
    return $registration;
    include("customer_login.php")

} else if ($action == 'register_product') {
    $customer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer');
    $get_customer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'get_customer');

    include("customer_login.php")
}
?>
```

What can I do to get this all to work correctly?

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? Do you get any errors? Wrong pages? Blank pages? Wrong username shown? Wrong product registered?

Comment: `<input type="text" action="login_customer" class="search">` That `action="login_customer"` attribute should most likely be `name="action" value="login_customer"` so you can access the field in PHP

Comment: As brombeer mentioned, give your inputs a `name` so `index.php` can parse the input when the form is submitted.  PHP will associate the input `name` with the `value` (what the customer entered).

Comment: I am getting a blank page once I hit the login button

Comment: All 3 files seem to need significant editing, not sure where you got this, but an "action" attribute for an input / submit seems wrong. Can't really analyze without all the files you're calling with `require()`. But I fixed the errors I could see if you want to cut and paste these 3 edited pages and run it : https://replit.com/@Bman70/php-form-code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have cut and pasted the files, I'm still getting a blank page coming up when I go to hit a button

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `customer_login.php`, you have wrong at form input `<input type="text" action="login_customer" class="search">` , there is nothing send to the `index.php` because name of post is not defined.

So, your code must like this.

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
<main>

    <h2>Customer Login</h2>
    <p>You must login before you can register a product.</p>
    
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="login_customer" class="search"> //edit action to name
        <input type="submit" value="Login"></p>

    </form>

</main>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I have changed the customer_login.php to what you have suggested, but now when I go to press the login button all I am getting up is a blank page of the index.php. I'm needing it to read the email address, go into the index.php and then produce on the product_register.php page the name of the customer with that specific email address and a drop down for them to select their product that they are registering. Then there is a register product button that then shows that they have registered their product